# Toolset to deploy clusters on Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, infrastructure, packer, terraform

I am using packer.io to deploy a single VM to Azure. The next step in my project is to deploy a cluster of VMs to Azure. Packer alone is not sufficient, in my opinion (correct me if I am wrong) to orchestrate deployment of clusters. So, I need something else to orchestrate the deployment. Since it is a cluster, each machine in it will need to know IP addresses of every other machine (my application is a distributed database.) I was looking at terraform.io, but its documentation does not have any examples when it comes to Azure. Are there any resources to get started? Is terraform what I need? Any other tools you would recommend?
Another complication is that I am trying to automate deployment of demo VMs for my customers. My current workflow is, using packer, create a VM, install my database, create necessary user accounts, upload certain staging directories to the VM. Then I take a snapshot to get my image. Later, this image is deployed from VMDepot by my clients (to their Azure accounts.) Again, for now, this is only a single-machine cluster. Later on, this will need to be a set of at least four machines. Is there a better workflow to accomplish this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has [an Azure provider](https://terraform.io/docs/providers/azure/index.html), though I think it had not yet been developed at the time you asked your original question.

Terraform allows the creation of multiple "copies" of the same resource, which is useful for creating clusters. However, passing in the IP addresses of all of the hosts together into those instances can be tricky since the provisioning step must wait until all of the instances have completed. A common workaround for this sort of sequencing is to use the undocumented `null_resource` to run a standalone provisioning step on the hosts. For example:

```
resource "azure_instance" "web" {
    name = "terraform-test"
    hosted_service_name = "${azure_hosted_service.example.name}"
    image = "Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS"
    size = "Basic_A1"
    storage_service_name = "yourstorage"
    location = "West US"
    username = "terraform"
    password = "Pass!admin123"

    # Tell Terraform to create 3 identical instances.
    count = 3

    endpoint {
        name = "SSH"
        protocol = "tcp"
        public_port = 22
        private_port = 22
    }
}

resource "null_resource" "provision" {
    count = 3

    connection {
        host = "${lookup(azura_instance.web.*.ip_address, count.index)}"
        user = "terraform"
        password = "Pass!admin123"
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "/usr/local/bin/configure-cluster ${join(" ", azura_instance.web.*.ip_address)}",
        ]
    }
}
```

The three copies of the null resource all depend on all three of the `azure_instance` resources, so it will not be created and provisioned until all of the instances are ready. Once the instances are all ready, each null resource is configured to connect to its corresponding instance (by index) and then run an imaginary `configure-cluster` command on its instance, passing in the full set of cluster IP addresses as arguments.

Note that provisioners run only at the initial creation of a resource. Updates to the resource do not re-run provisioners. Since the null resource doesn't actually represent a real infrastructure resource, the provisioning steps can easily be re-run by "tainting" it so that Terraform will re-create it on the next `apply`:

```
terraform taint null_resource.provision
```